# How to switch scope of window after opening a new tab by selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scope

In selenium tests, I open a new tab by the following:

```
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click($(By.cssSelector(".btn-xs"))).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

After the above, I need to switch scope of the window to check some elements on this tab (but I won't make this tab visible, it should be hidden, without focus).

I tried to use WindowHandles by the following:

```
java.util.Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
```

But it contains only first initial tab and 1 element (while there are two open tabs in the driver).

How should I do this?

Comment: Do the same thing and put it into an arraylist and see if you can see the 2nd tab.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click($(By.cssSelector(".btn-xs"))).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();

//wait for few seconds for loading site
    for (String windows : driver.getWindowHandles()) {

                driver.switchTo().window(windows);

                if (driver.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("xyz.com")) {

                //Your Operation
                   }
                if (driver.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("yzx.com")) {
    //Your Operation
                    }


            }
```

Here What I did, I click on redirect link.And wait for few second for site load.After redirection, I return desire tab link start with, where you can give other condition also!!

Hope it will help you

Comment: It doesn't work because In wd.getWindowHandles() I am getting only one element, not two.

Comment: here nothing about the element.windowhandles will check your all tabs and find your desire tab

Comment: I meant the objects in array, I don't get the second at all by your code.

Comment: Change your link by replacing  Link + "xyz.com"

Comment: no, looks like you didn't catch the problem. getWindowHandles() - executes only ones but I need twice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156675/discussion-between-tatyana-durova-and-zsbappa).

Comment: Okay i will available within 30 min